# can't open shape file with GeoPandas

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I don't seem to be able to open the zip3.zip shape file I download from (http://www.vdstech.com/usa-data.aspx)

Here is my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
data = gpd.read_file("data/zip3.shp")
```

this gives me the error:

```
CPLE_AppDefinedError: b'Recode from CP437 to UTF-8 failed with the error: "Invalid argument".'
```

Comment: Highly relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243879/brecode-from-ansi-1252-to-utf-8-failed-with-the-error-invalid-argument-geo) for this situation (perhaps duplicates maybe?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276340/3908170) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243879/brecode-from-ansi-1252-to-utf-8-failed-with-the-error-invalid-argument-geo) question, seems like your dataset contains non-UTF characters. If you are facing this similar issue, chances are that using `encoding-"utf-8"` won't help as Fiona's `open()` call will still fail.

If other solutions don't work, two solutions I propose that solved this issue are:

1. Open your shapefile on a GIS editor (like QGis), then save it again making sure you select the `Encoding` option to "UTF-8". After this you should have no problem when calling `gpd.read_file("data/zip3.shp")`.
2. You can also achieve this format change in Python using GDAL, by reading your shapefile and saving it again. This will effectively change the encoding to UTF-8, as this is the default encoding as indicated in the [docs](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Driver-class.html#CreateDataSource) for the `CreateDataSource()` method. For this try the following code snippet:

   ```
   from osgeo import ogr

   driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
   ds = driver.Open("nbac_2016_r2_20170707_1114.shp", 0) #open your shapefile
   #get its layer
   layer = ds.GetLayer()

   #create new shapefile to convert
   ds2 = driver.CreateDataSource('convertedShape.shp')
   #create a Polygon layer, as the one your Shapefile has
   layer2 = ds2.CreateLayer('', None, ogr.wkbPolygon)
   #iterate over all features of your original shapefile
   for feature in layer:
      #and create a new feature on your converted shapefile with those features
      layer2.CreateFeature(feature)
   #proper closing
   ds = layer = ds2 = layer2 = None
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use QGis per your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this `shapefile` doesn't have an associated cpg specifying the encoding of the `.dbf` file, and then falling back to trying to use your default system encoding isn't working either. You should be able to open this with:

```
data = gpd.read_file("data/zip3.shp", encoding="utf-8")
```

`geopandas` relies on `fiona` for shapefile reading, and you may need to upgrade your `fiona` version for this to work; see some discussion [here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/510)

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably have GDAL installed, I recommend converting the file to UTF-8 using the CLI:

```
ogr2ogr output.shp input.shp -lco ENCODING=UTF-8
```

Worked like a charm for me. It's much faster than QGIS and can be used in a cluster environment. I also posted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243879/brecode-from-ansi-1252-to-utf-8-failed-with-the-error-invalid-argument-geo/49525045#49525045). Specifying the encoding in `geopandas` did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file is dependent on other files.
I faced the same problem and when I copied other files that this `shapefile` is dependent on, the code ran correctly but requested to install another package called `descartes`. When I installed the package, the code ran correctly